# Which design pattern to use

Tags: java, design-patterns

In an interview this is the question that is asked:

> You have to write a program that take a directory name (e.g. D:\XYZ)
>   and a regular expression (e.g. "*Olivea*") as an argument. And it will
>   list down all the files in the given directory with the name matched
>   with the regular expression.

I have made a simple program from this:

```
package temp;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class FileSearch1 {

    static ArrayList l = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String folderName = "D:\\"; // the folder path in which you want to
                                    // search
        String strPattern = "Olivea"; // Pattern what you want to search
        final boolean searchinFile = true; // if you want to search in file keep
                                            // it true for folder search keep it
                                            // false
        File f = new File("D:\\");
        Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(strPattern);
        sunny(f, pattern1, searchinFile);

    }

    public static void sunny(File f, Pattern pattern1,
            final boolean searchinFileOnly) {
        File[] f1 = f.listFiles();
        if (f1 == null)
            return;
        int k = f1.length;
        // System.out.println(k);
        int i = 0;
        while (i < k) {
            File f2 = f1[i];
            if (f2.isDirectory() && !searchinFileOnly) {
                Matcher match1 = pattern1.matcher(f2.getName());
                while (match1.find()) {
                    l.add("");
                    System.out.println(f2.getName());
                }
            } else if (f2.isFile() && searchinFileOnly) {
                Matcher match1 = pattern1.matcher(f2.getName());
                while (match1.find()) {
                    l.add("");
                    System.out.println(f2.getName());
                }
            }

            sunny(f2, pattern1, searchinFileOnly);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

After the written test, **the interviewer asked me that which design
pattern could you use in this**. Would you please suggest me the various
design patterns that we can implement in this code.?

**Please help me how to apply composite and iterator pattern in this? Help will really be appreciated**

Comment: @Dennis thanks dennis for your comment, how can I fix this? please suggest.

Comment: every one should come from meta

Comment: If I was being interviewed and was asked which pattern to apply I would walk out of the interview.  If I were interviewing you I would have ended the interview after seeing the method called "sunny".

Comment: The question shouldn't even be "what pattern should i use?".  That way lies overengineering and eventual madness.  Not the least reason for which being that there are very few cases where one pattern would solve the whole problem.  And in those cases, the answer is almost always quite obvious to anyone with a clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that you have missed the No.1 Golden Rule of coding, namely that everything should be named correctly, you could use the [Iterator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) and [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) patterns.

Composite would allow files and directories to be treated similarly.

Iterator is used to traverse a container and access the container's elements. The iterator pattern decouples algorithms from containers.

Comment: It would be a great help if you can explain how to apply iterator and composite in the above scenario. or by using some code samples

Comment: I'm sorry I can't write your code for you. There should be plenty of examples of using these patterns on the web.

Comment: @Mitch how iterator would help here.

Comment: @MitchWheat I think java.io.File is taking care of all the complexities you mention in composite pattern. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) where you create an interface with generic methods.

You will provide a class which implements that interface. This way you can separate implementation details. Depending upon the input data you can write more classes with different algorithms. At runtime you can select whatever class implementation you want. This is only alternative. I suggest you to learn [GOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29) patterns.

Comment: if I want to write only one implementation algo...how can this strategy pattern will come into picture. didn't get your point.

Comment: Design Patterns:
Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software  read this book

Comment: I suggest this only for multiple implementations